Why does a newly installed storage device appear and reappear multiple times?
I use Kali Linux and installed a 480G SSD disk by myself. I use sudo fdisk -l to check. Sometime the disk appears and sometime not.
I divided the disk into 2 partitions: one has Window system and the other is an exFAT partition.
Is there a way to fix this disappear and appear problem?
sudo fdisk -l        

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: PM991a NVMe Samsung 256GB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EF71B87C-99F1-4D36-B775-33510C2028E1

Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1  2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2  1050624  49879039  48828416  23.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 49879040  69410815  19531776   9.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 69410816  71411711   2000896   977M Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p5 71411712  75317247   3905536   1.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 75317248 500117503 424800256 202.6G Linux filesystem
—------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: WD Green 2.5 480
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AE4E90D4-DEC6-4200-A6F8-CDE44E1B3EC7

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    34815   32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2   34816 409602047 409567232 195.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  409602048 937699327 528097280 251.8G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: PM991a NVMe Samsung 256GB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EF71B87C-99F1-4D36-B775-33510C2028E1

Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1  2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2  1050624  49879039  48828416  23.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 49879040  69410815  19531776   9.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 69410816  71411711   2000896   977M Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p5 71411712  75317247   3905536   1.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 75317248 500117503 424800256 202.6G Linux filesystem


I assume you have ruled out the SATA cable as the problem. Is this a new drive, not a new used drive?

This sounds like a hardware problem. Check out the output of dmesg to see if the kernel is logging anything.
